# A problem with the equivalent form of Frankl conjecture.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, conjectures

The Union Closed Sets Conjecture (or Frankl conjecture) is described in this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-closed_sets_conjecture.

It is known that this problem has an equivalent form in terms of graphs.

Namely: Frankl conjecture is equivalent to assertion that in any graph $G=(V,\mathcal{E})$, such $|\mathcal{E}|\ge 1$, there exists two adjacent vertices that each of them belongs to at most half of the maximal independent sets.

But here is the problem:

Imagine the following graph $G=(V,\mathcal{E})$. Where :

$V = \{1,2,3\}$ and $\mathcal{E}=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$

The only maximal independent set is $\{1,3\}$

Let's take any two vertices, for instance $1,2$. We see that $1\in\{1,3\}$ so "$1$" belongs to more than half of the maximal independent sets. That contradicts the conjecture.

However i strongly believe that i made some mistakes.

> Where is mistake?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{2\}$ is also a maximal independent set - no vertices can be added to it without creating an edge.